# Python, Django: Alternative to a raw-sql-query

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

Good evening,

I would like to ask, if there's a different method to a raw sql query to update items by a certain condition inside my views.py? For example, I know I could do an insert query like this:

**models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
    value = models.IntegerField()
```

**views.py**

```
def something(request):
    ...
    qs = Person(name="John Doe", age=34, value=10)
    qs.save()
    ...
```

Is there a similiar method for updating all "Persons" if they fit a certain condition?

```
...
qs = Person("UPDATE Person SET value=5 WHERE age < 30") # or something like this
qs.save()
...
```

Thanks for all your help and advice and a great weekend to all of you!

Comment: `Person.objects.filter(age__lt=30).update(value=5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [**`.update(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) to update records of the corresponding table, and use [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) to specify *what* items to update.

You thus can filter with:

```
Person.objects.filter(age__lt=30).update(value=5)
```

Here we make use of the [**`__lt`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#lt) to specify that the age should be *less than* 30.